# html table column width

Tags: html, css

How to fix bottom column ? Width 50% not really working. I want to do 2 row and 3 row bottom same width.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="width:50%;">Cell A</td>
    <td style="width:50%;">Cell B</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Cell A</td>
    <td>Cell B</td>
    <td>Cell B</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you need to fix the question.  You are mixing up Rows with Columns.  Rows are horizontal and Columns are vertical.  I think your question is, "How do i get 2 Column Headers and Rows with 3 Columns?"  Is this correct?

Comment: Not possible with simple html table. Firstly you have to use colspan attribute to span a column to multiple columns but that does not give desired result either. You'd have to use nested tables or use CSS with divs.

Answer (score 6):

Table columns are inter-connected. So that if you place some content that forces a cell to grow wider, the entire column grows wider.

That means that all rows must have the same number of cells. However, you can merge 2 or more cells by using `colspan` attribute.

If you want to have 2 columns on one row and 3 columns on others, you probably want to set 6 cells and use `colspan` in both cases:

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table style="width: 100%;">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3" style="width:50%;">Cell A</td>
    <td colspan="3" style="width:50%;">Cell B</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">Cell A</td>
    <td colspan="2">Cell B</td>
    <td colspan="2">Cell C</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

I made them 6 columns as it's easier to visualize. But, in reality the 2 columns on each side can be merged, as they are always colspan-ed together:

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table style="width: 100%;">
  <col width="33.3333%">
  <col width="16.6667%">
  <col width="16.6667%">
  <col width="33.3333%">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">Cell A</td>
    <td colspan="2">Cell B</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell A</td>
    <td colspan="2">Cell B</td>
    <td>Cell C</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `colspan='2'` on first row second column.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="width:50%;">Cell A</td>
    <td colspan='2' style="width:50%;">Cell B</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Cell A</td>
    <td>Cell B</td>
    <td>Cell B</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use colspan to tell the browser how many columns to want a cell to occupy:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    table,
    th,
    td {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <table width="100%">
    <tr>
      <td>Cell A</td>
      <td colspan="2">Cell B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell A</td>
      <td>Cell B</td>
      <td>Cell B</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</body>

</html>
```